# Помогите найти почтовый сервис

Tags: email, smtp, спам

Есть компания, занимающаяся тестированием персонала. Она оказывает услуги клиентам, рассылая по их запросам на почтовые ящики приглашения для тестирования: ссылка на тест на сайте компании, а также сопроводительное письмо.

Некоторое время компания пользовалась почтой Яндекса для домена, и все шло хорошо, пока клиенты не начали рассылать сообщения большими группами. Яндекс такое запрещает и начинает вырубать ящик на сутки, если что-то подозрительное по его мнению ушло в рассылку. Договориться со службой поддержки насчет ложных срабатываний (потому что по факту это не спам) не удалось. В итоге компания ищет какой-нибудь другой сервис, в том числе возможно платно, лишь бы подобных проблем не возникало.

Пробовали Zoho Mail - в итоге на тот же Яндекс некоторые письма попадают в greylisting и уходят только через полчаса (но при этом попадают во входящие), некоторые попадают в папку Спам, причем непонятно по каким причинам (есть два письма, различающиеся только шестью знаками в ссылке, по тому же адресату - одно попало в спам, другое нет). Яндекс использует много кто, и не хочется, чтобы письма доходили через полчаса или вообще не доходили. Видимо, он считает Zoho недоверенным источником писем, или просто DNS недавно обновился? SPF, DKIM и DMARC настроены корректно, письма проходят проверку mail-tester.com c рейтингом 9/10.

В общем, сведущим в принципах работы с такими задачами просьба дать пару советов, подсказать, что делать или на какой сервак податься. Я ранее такими делами не занимался. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас большинство сервисов блокирует большое кол-во поступления писем на почту, если источник считается не известен, то скорее всего попадет в Спам, или вообще заблокируется. В gmail например с этим очень все строго, порой даже письма от известных игровых платформ, наподобие Steam попадает в Спам. Если вы просите почту, для рассылки сообщений, то можете попробовать использовать почту AOL.COM или Gmail.com тот же ( Письма, которые приходят от Gmail считаются в большей степени доверительным )

Comment: В Gmail ограничение на 2000 писем в сутки, в том числе для платных аккаунтов, и насколько я читал, превысить его нельзя. Вообще везде в таких "почтах для домена" есть подобные ограничения, не позволяющие делать автоматическую рассылку. Например, на Zoho.com. Я вроде бы настроил Zoho так, чтобы письма в спам не попадали, но однажды мне просто заблокировали ящик за массовую рассылку.
Неохота поднимать свой SMTP-сервер, поскольку с ним может быть еще больше проблем - mail.ru, насколько я слышал, вообще не любит, когда на него приходят письма непонятно откуда и не пускает их даже в папку "Спам".

Comment: @AnthonyLegos Читая ваш текст, порой задумываюсь, вам главное чтобы на конкретно какой то почтовый сервер письма попадали, или вам нужна почта, для рассылки на любые почтовые сервера? Когда я давал ответ по Gmail, то я имел в виду, что если кому то будет приходить письма от данного сервиса, то они на 80 процентов будут иметь доверительный характер. Попробуйте почту aol.com. А вообще, везде придется покупать, так скажем, премиум и регистрировать свое доменное имя для большего успеха.

Comment: В первую очередь, чтобы сам сервис не резал мне исходящий трафик, так как якобы я спамлю. С такой проблемой сталкиваюсь уже не в первый раз. Просто доходимость писем еще можно как-то контролировать - она повышается, если правильно подписать письма и домен - а вот когда сам сервис режет и блокирует письма, потому что "вы разослали 20 похожих писем, что-то подозрительно" - на это повлиять никак нельзя, это условия пользовательского соглашения.

Comment: @AnthonyLegos пробуйте платную aol.com или любые иностранные сервера